# How do I read from a file into a 2d array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm working on a program that plays a matching game with the user. The code compiles but when I try to run it, the table that appears has garbage values in it.

My input files look like this:

```
//p4data1.dat
A
F
B
D
C
E
F
B
D
E
A
C
```

```
//p4data2.dat
F
B
D
C
A
F
E
A
C
D
B
E
```

and my current code is:

```
void fileAndRandom(char letArr[][COLUMN], int rows, int columns) {
  int random = rand() % 2 + 1;
  ifstream readFile;
  if(random == 1) {
    readFile.open("p4data1.dat");
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      for(int k = 0; k < columns; k++) {
        readFile >> letArr[i][k];
      }
    }
    }else if(random == 2) {
      readFile.open("p4data2.dat");
      for(int b = 0; b < rows; b++) {
        for(int a = 0; a < columns; a++) {
          readFile >> letArr[b][a];
        }
      }
    }
  readFile.close();
}
```

I'm stuck on how to read it in. Also i can't use vectors because I haven't been taught to do so yet.

Comment: read dat files as bytes, then do whatever you want with the bytes.  std::string and std::vector are good options for containing bytes.

Comment: At the end of each line is "\n" or "\r\n", should ignore it.

Comment: What dies the table with the garbage values look like?

Comment: actually i realized the reason it wasn't working was because i never called the function in main lol

Answer (score 0):

You should use `std::vector` instead of array because `std::vector` is a variable size container and you don't always know how many elements the input.txt file contains. The complete working program [below](https://onlinegdb.com/37NfSEgdM) shows how to read from a text file and store that information in a **2D `std::vector`**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include<fstream>
int main() {
    std::string line, word;

    
    std::ifstream inFile("input.txt");
    
    //create/use a std::vector instead of builit in array 
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vec;
    
    if(inFile)
    {
        while(getline(inFile, line, '\n'))        
        {
            //create a temporary vector that will contain all the columns
            std::vector<std::string> tempVec;
            
            
            std::istringstream ss(line);
            
            //read word by word 
            while(ss >> word)
            {
                //std::cout<<"word:"<<word<<std::endl;
                //add the word to the temporary vector 
                tempVec.push_back(word);
            
            }      
            
            //now all the words from the current line has been added to the temporary vector 
            vec.emplace_back(tempVec);
        }    
    }
    
    else 
    {
        std::cout<<"file cannot be opened"<<std::endl;
    }
    
    inFile.close();
    
    //lets check out the elements of the 2D vector so the we can confirm if it contains all the right elements(rows and columns)
    for(std::vector<std::string> &newvec: vec)
    {
        for(const std::string &elem: newvec)
        {
            std::cout<<elem<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    
    /*another way to print out the elements of the 2D vector would be as below 
    for(int row = 0; row < vec.size(); ++row)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < vec.at(row).size(); ++col)
        {
            std::cout<<vec.at(row).at(col)<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    */
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/37NfSEgdM). At the end of my program i have printed out the elements of the **2d vector** so that we can confirm if it contains all the elements correctly.

The **advantage** of using std::vector is that you don't have to know the number of rows and columns beforehand in your input file and there is no need to pass(or allocate memory for) `row` and `column`.